# JQuery-Mobile Multiple Content roles

Tags: jquery-mobile

Are we allowed to have multiple content roles in a page?

The documentation suggests there should be one but doesn't explicitly say that there should only be one

I have been using the content roles to provide a logical grouping of areas of my pages. 
This also provides padding and background gradients to give a nice separation of grouped elements, without the addition of my own css -  we have avoided adding css where possible to allow the upgrade path to be as easy as possible

If so, is there any other role which would be better suited or should I be using standard ui- CSS rules?
.. like ui-body or can you suggest an other?

Would there be any place for a 'section' role which would do the same job?

Many thanks, Ant

originally asked here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-content-roles

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at **fieldset**, which I'm using quite a bit. Also gives you *legend* as sort-of section header

Another nice combination I'm using is JQM collapsibles with the [1140 CSS grid](http://cssgrid.net/). The Grid allows to do rows of max 12 cells, like so:

```
     <container>
       <row>
         <cell1><cell2><cell3><cell4><cell5>...<cell12>
         // cells can be anything from 1-12, so 4/4/4, 2/4/4/2...
       </row>
       <row>
         // new row 
       </row>
     </container>
```

On smartphone the cells change to 100% width, so you will have:

```
    <container>
       <row>
         <cell1>
         <cell2>
         <cell3>
         <cell4>
         <cell5>
         ...
         <cell12>             
       </row>
     </container>
```

I'm mixing this with collapsibles (no additional CSS needed) like so:

```
     <container>
       <collapsible-set>
         <collapsible-1>
            <row>
               <cell><fieldest><content>
               <cell><fieldest><content>
            <row>
         </collabsible-1>
         <collapsible-2>
            <row>
               <cell><fieldest><content>
               <cell><fieldest><content>
            <row>
         </collabsible-2>
         ...
```

Looks nice on Smartphone and Tablet. I'm using it for long forms mostly.